# Shell script works directly, but has a syntax error via crontab

Tags: shell, crontab

I have a shell script to automate a git commit and push every night:

`auto_git_push.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

function automate(){
    git add .
    git commit -am "automated push $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
    git push -u
}

cd ~/htdocs
automate
```

If I run this command, the script works as expected: `. ~/bin/auto_git_push.sh`

However, with this crontab line (set to every minute for testing)

`* * * * * sh /home/hookedonwinter/bin/auto_git_push.sh`

I get the following error:

`/home/hookedonwinter/bin/auto_git_push.sh: 3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

What is causing this syntax error?

Thanks!

**Edit based on accepted answer:**

Changed the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

automate() {
    git add .
    git commit -am "automated push $(date +"%Y-%m-%d")"
    git push -u
}

cd ~/htdocs
automate
```

And the crontab line to:

`* * * * * /bin/bash /home/hookedonwinter/bin/auto_git_push.sh`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As John mentioned, it is a matter of your script being interpreted differently in the two environments (using `/bin/sh` under `cron`, and using your existing shell, which is probably `/bin/bash` when you source it in directly). Actually, `/bin/sh` is usually just a symlink to `/bin/bash`, and the bash executable behaves differently depending on the name under which it was invoked, but that's just an aside.

Here, the easiest way to fix your issue is probably just to specify

```
/bin/bash /home/hookedonwinter/bin/auto_git_push.sh
```

as the command to run under cron.

Comment: Or you can set SHELL variable in the crontab file (if you are using debian) to SHELL=/bin/bash

Answer (score 2):

The cron environment is interpreting the inlined command differently than your shell environment. I'm guessing your shell is /bin/bash, which means it's running in a different shell entirely than it does in cron (the ". " construct reads the command stream into the shell, it doesn't invoke the shell in the shebang line). I'm not sure what syntax you need to use in /bin/sh, but I would start by trying simple backticks in place of the $( and ). Once you find something that works, you can either use it or continue searching for something more appealing to your aesthetics.

Comment: I started to work on this, and someone else (in real life proximity) suggested the same thing that @jjlin just did, which worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different shells at work here. `/bin/sh` is the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) shell (syntax based on the Bourne shell). `/bin/bash` is the [Bourne Again Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html), a.k.a. Bash. It is POSIX-compliant, but adds its own syntax, among other things. Depending on your system setup, `/bin/sh` could be a symlink to some other POSIX-compliant shell like [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell) or [ash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell). The important point is that it expects [POSIX shell syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), without Bash extras.

In Bash scripting, functions can be declared with the `function` reserved word, which makes the parentheses optional. This means that in Bash, the following are all valid function declarations:

```
function foo() { true; }
function bar { true; }
baz() { true; }
```

But according to POSIX shell syntax, only the last one, `baz() { true; }`, is valid.

Based on the answer you've chosen to this question, you can see that invoking the script directly with `/bin/bash` will cause Bash to interpret your script, with no problems. For future reference, though, only use POSIX syntax in scripts that start with a `#!/bin/sh` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), and use `#!/bin/bash` for scripts that contain Bash-specific syntax.